# Navigating auxiliary route throws exception

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Given this routing config:

```
export const ROUTES: Route[] = [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'projects', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'projects', component: ProjectsComponent,
        children: [
          { path: 'projectlist', component: ProjectListComponent, outlet: 'sidemenu' }
        ]
      }
    ];
```

calling

```
this.router.navigate(['projects(sidemenu:projectlist)']);
```

throws

> error_handler.js:47 EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot
>   match any routes. URL Segment: 'projects(sidemenu%3Aprojectlist)'

Comment: Try to add "/" after projects - projects/(sidemenu:projectlist)

Answer (score 0):

This setup worked. Much cleaner, but not sure if conventional.

```
export const ROUTES: Route[] = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'projects', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'projects',
    children: [
      { path: '', component: ProjectsComponent },
      { path: '', component: ProjectListComponent, outlet: 'sidemenu' }
    ]
  }
];
```